# Will users be able to update app (which has been downloaded from different app, e.g. Mi Store) in Play Store (or vice verse)?

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

Imagine, I have my app released in *X Strore* and *Play Store*. Then I release update in both of the stores. If user downloads my app from X Store before I release the update. Then, after I have updated, user goes to *Play Store* to update the app that has been downloaded from X Store.

Is this gonna work?

If yes, do I have to use the same signing keys for apk that I am going to distrubute to *X Store* and *Play Store*?

Comment: Play store will not attempt to update apps installed from third party sources. Signing keys don't matter.

Comment: @Pawel thank you for your response. Could you please provide any documentations/links on that?

Comment: I just found [this blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/google-play-security-metadata-and.html) that says there is some apk recognition if you mirror it from the play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if the apk is signed by the same key.
The first update may not be automatic, though.

An easy way to test this if you have an app already published to the play store is to manually install an older version of the apk to your phone with `adb` and then going to the play store to check for updates.
The phone should not have the app already installed for this test.

It will be impossible to do if the signing keys are different. This is a security feature of Android, not of the distribution channel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have already opted-in for Google App Signing because and let the Google to create my signing key. I think there is no way that I achieve this right now. Sad, that I rushed a little bit.

Comment: If you don't have too many users yet, you can unpublish and try again.